# emitting both webcam stream and chat to specific room using socket.io nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have successfully implemented streaming webcam and chat at the same time using node.js and socket.io, I have an emit.html page for whoever is initiating the stream, and a visualize.html page for the clients or recipient, and  but I have challenge in attaching webcam stream to only room which is created by the administrator, please how can I emit the webcam to a specific room only.
This is my server code below

```
const express = require("express");
const app = new express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
const formatMessage = require("./utils/messages");
const {
   userJoin,
   getCurrentUser,
   userLeave,
   getRoomUsers,
 } = require("./utils/users");

 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

 app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

 const botName = "Admin";

 app.get("/", function (req, res) {
 res.redirect("index.html");
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
socket.on("stream", function (image) {
socket.broadcast.emit("stream", image);
});

//Join Room
socket.on("joinRoom", ({ username, room }) => {
const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room);

socket.join(user.room);

// Welcome current user
socket.emit("message", formatMessage(botName, "Welcome to Class!"));

// Broadcast when a user connects
socket.broadcast
  .to(user.room)
  .emit(
    "message",
    formatMessage(botName, `${user.username} has joined the class`)
  );

  // Send users and room info
  io.to(user.room).emit("roomUsers", {
    room: user.room,
    users: getRoomUsers(user.room),
  });
});

// Listen for chatMessage
socket.on("chatMessage", (msg) => {
  const user = getCurrentUser(socket.id);

  io.to(user.room).emit("message", formatMessage(user.username, msg));
});

// Runs when client disconnects
socket.on("disconnect", () => {
const user = userLeave(socket.id);

if (user) {
  io.to(user.room).emit(
    "message",
    formatMessage(botName, `${user.username} has left the class`)
  );

  // Send users and room info
  io.to(user.room).emit("roomUsers", {
    room: user.room,
    users: getRoomUsers(user.room),
  });
 }
});
});
http.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Please check the git repo for the full project, I don't mind any adjustments to make it better.
https://github.com/timotech/screen-cast
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the stream socket to the joinRoom socket
This is the adjustment of the code:

```
socket.on("joinRoom", ({ username, room }) => {
const user = userJoin(socket.id, username, room);

socket.join(user.room);

//Display webcam to user
socket.on("stream", function (image) {
  socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit("stream", image);
});
…
```

Now everything works as expected. But the only challenge i'm having now is that I hosted it on Heroku, but it doesn't work as expected.

This is the link to the Heroku hosting.
For Teachers: https://screencastst.herokuapp.com/
For Students access: https://screencastst.herokuapp.com/students.html

Teachers are the only ones having access to camera, that's why teachers have a different link and students can only see whichever teacher that is teaching their class, that's also why the difference for the link
But the chat is not working, that is the challenge I have now. But works perfectly on localhost
Thanks